# Shrink heightConstraint animation issue

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

I'm trying to make pull up menu view

I made this pull up view using xib and attached to ViewController

and added pan gesture on pull up view

lastly, I updated height constraint using pan gesture for animation.

```
func pullUpControlView(_ pullUpControlView: PullUpControlView, didPanned height: CGFloat, animated: Bool) {
    self.pullUpControlViewHeightConstraint?.constant = height
    if animated {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 10, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

this is my code it's animation works fine when view got maximum height,

but when minimising view, view is minimised immediately and start move to down slowly (weird animation)

how can I make this animation correctly (shrink height from top to bottom)

[image]

Comment: you are saying view minimised immediately and moving down...!
What you are expecting from the view?
What should it (view) do.?

Comment: Could you add some screenshots of what you are trying to archive and add pull up view constraints?

Comment: I added my situation, I just want my view height shrink smoothly, but it's not working

Comment: Please upload a sample project reproducing the issue. In my opinion, the code you posted doesn't seem to be problematic. I guess your problem is from elsewhere on your project. Are you calling `layoutIfNeeded()` somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

```
func pullUpControlView(_ pullUpControlView: PullUpControlView, didPanned height: CGFloat, animated: Bool) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, animations: {() -> Void in
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: {(_ finished: Bool) -> Void in
        self.pullUpControlViewHeightConstraint?.constant = height
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        //if animation is finished ("finished" == *YES*), then hidden = "finished" ... (aka hidden = *YES*)
    })
}
```